# Scala generic functions

Tags: scala, generics

I have an abstract class

```
abstract class Foo {
  def foo(a: Int): Int
  ...
}

// Usage
new Foo {
  def foo(a: Int) = {
    println("Foo")
    a
  }
}
```

I frequently see a companion object to make this a little less verbose for callers (e.g. the Play framework).

```
object Foo {
  def apply(f: Int => Int) = new Foo {
    def foo(a: Int) = f(a)
  }
}

// Usage
Foo { a =>
  println("Foo")
  a
}
```

---

But suppose I make the method generic

```
abstract class Foo {
  def foo(a: T): T
  ...
}

// Usage
new Foo {
  def foo(a: T) = {
    println("Foo")
    a
  }
}
```

Can I still use a companion object, i.e. can I apply generic type parameters to a function, rather than a method or class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this by emulating `rank 2` polymorphism. Based on [this article](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/) you can do:

```
trait ~>[F[_],G[_]] {
  def apply[A](a: F[A]): G[A]
}

type Id[A] = A

abstract class Foo {
  def foo[T](a: T): T
}

object Foo {
  def apply(f: Id ~> Id) = new Foo {
    def foo[T](a: T): T = f(a)
  }
}

val fun = new (Id ~> Id) { def apply[T](a: T): T = { println("Foo"); a } }
val foo = Foo(fun)
foo.foo(1)
foo.foo("String")
```

Comment: @PaulDraper - So you want `Foo.foo` to be generic?